# Value of <select> Input Not Recognized when Selected By jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

In an application I am working, an option in select drop-down box should be dynamically selected based upon the input of a radio button. However, while the value does appear to be set visually (it is displayed in the drop-down menu box), it is not being recognized as such. To elaborate, I still receive a "This field is required" message even though a value *is* selected ([using the jQuery validation plug-in](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) , and the data is not being posted properly to my PHP script.

```
 $("input[name='visionID']").change(function() {
          $("#visionDisplay").val($(this).attr("data-insurance-display"));
       if($(this).attr("id") == "e" || $(this).attr("id") == "d") {
           $("#visionDependentsEnrolled").val("false");
           $("#visionDependentContainer").hide();               

       }  else {
           $("#visionDependentsEnrolled").val("true");

                $("#visionDependentContainer").show();
            if    ($(this).attr("id") == "s") {

                    $(".visionRelationship").val("Spouse");      
                    $(".visionRelationship option").not(":selected").prop("disabled", true).css("background-color", "#D3D3D3");
                }
            else if    ($(this).attr("id") == "c") {

                $(".visionRelationship").val("Dependent");         
                $(".visionRelationship option").not(":selected").prop("disabled", true).css("background-color", "#D3D3D3");

            } else {
                $(".visionRelationship option").not(":selected").prop("disabled", false).css("background-color", "white");
            }

       }
    });
```

I have looked around, and it seems as if simply use .val() should work, but this is not the case. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT:

A portion of my HTML:

```
<div id='visionDependentContainer'>
        <div class='form-group-sm'>
            <label class='control-label col-md-6'>How many dependents would you like to add? Please include
                both your spouse (if applicable) and any dependent children. <span class='requiredMark'>*</span>
            </label>
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <select name='visionDependentCount' class='required form-control' id='visionDependentCount'><option
                        value=''>Select</option>
                    <option value='1'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '1') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>One</option>
                    <option value='2'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '2') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>Two</option>
                    <option value='3'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '3') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>Three</option>
                    <option value='4'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '4') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>Four</option>
                    <option value='5'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '5') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>Five</option>
                    <option value='6'
                        <?php (isset($visionDependentCount) && $visionDependentCount == '6') ? print 'selected' : '' ?>>Six</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='clearfix'></div>

        <div class='table-responsive'>
            <table class='table table-condensed' id='visionDependentTable'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Full Name <span class='requiredMark'>*</span></th>
                    <th>SSN <span class='requiredMark'>*</span></th>
                    <th>Gender <span class='requiredMark'>*</span></th>
                    <th>Date of Birth <span class='requiredMark'>*</span></th>
                    <th>Relationship <span class='requiredMark'>*</span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='text' class='required' name='visionFirstName1' id='visionFirstName1'
                        placeholder='First'
                        value='<?php (isset($visionFirstName1)) ? print $visionFirstName1 : print "" ?>' /> <input
                        type='text' class='required' name='visionLastName1' id='visionLastName1' placeholder='Last'
                        value='<?php (isset($visionLastName1)) ? print $visionLastName1 : print "" ?>' /></td>
                    <td><input type='text' class='ssn required' maxlength="9" name='visionSSN1' id='visionSSN1'
                        value='<?php (isset($visionSSN1)) ? print $visionSSN1 : print "" ?>' /></td>
                    <td><select name='visionGender1' class='required' id='visionGender1'>
                            <option value='M'
                                <?php (isset($visionGender1) && $visionGender1 == "M") ? print "selected" : '' ?>>Male</option>
                            <option value='F'
                                <?php (isset($visionGender1) && $visionGender1 == "F") ? print "selected" : '' ?>>Female</option>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><select name="visionMonth1" class='required' id="visionMonth1">
                            <option value=''>..</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "01") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='01'>01</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "02") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='02'>02</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "03") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='03'>03</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1)&& $visionMonth1 == "04") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='04'>04</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "05") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='05'>05</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "06") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='06'>06</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "07") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='07'>07</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "08") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='08'>08</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "09") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='09'>09</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "10") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='10'>10</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "11") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='11'>11</option>
                            <option
                                <?php (isset($visionMonth1) && $visionMonth1 == "12") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>
                                value='12'>12</option>
                    </select> <input type="text" class='required day' name="visionDay1" id="visionDay1"
                        value='<?php (isset($visionDay1)) ? print $visionDay1 : print "" ?>' placeholder="Day" /> <input
                        type='text' class='required year' name='visionYear1' id='visionYear1'
                        value='<?php (isset($visionYear1)) ? print $visionYear1 : print "" ?>' placeholder="Year" /></td>
                    <td><select class='required visionRelationship' name='visionRelationship1' id='visionRelationship1'><option
                                value=''>Select</option>
                            <option value='Spouse'
                                <?php (isset($visionRelationship1) && $visionRelationship1 == "Spouse") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>>Spouse
                            </option>
                            <option value='Dependent'
                                <?php (isset($visionRelationship1) && $visionRelationship1 == "Dependent") ? print "selected" : print "" ?>>Dependent
                            </option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: can you post html code ?

Comment: @niceman Certainly, I have edited to include some of my HTML code. Thanks.